# Typescript Postmessage fails with one argument, and two

Tags: typescript

Have Typescript project.

When this: `postMessage(result);`

I get this..

`Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.`Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.

When this: `postMessage(result, '*');`

I get this..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Overload resolution failed.
    at runParser
```

What does Typescript want here? Is it one or two arguments? And why is this causing an issue?

Comment: Well the first one is obviously wrong because it takes 2 or 3 parameters.  See the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage.  The second one should be `window.postMessage`, where `window` is the window you're posting to.

Comment: here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-post-message

Comment: This error happens in the worker scope, not the scope with Window

Comment: Right, sorry.  That's definitely odd because 1 value is allowed in that case.  I found a similar question that might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299899/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-dedicatedworkerglobalscope-the-provided-va.

Comment: Oh, try navigating to `postMessage` in your editor (eg. ctrl-click in VSCode).  I bet it's pointing to the version for the window object, not the worker version.  That's why it's complaining I bet.  Try being more explicit (I think the syntax is `self.postMessage(result)`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I strongly type a TypeScript web worker file with postMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950248/how-do-i-strongly-type-a-typescript-web-worker-file-with-postmessage)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MessageChannel's port postMessage function, then you have to pass only one parameter.

```
event.ports[0].postMessage(data)
```

If you are using window.postMessage, then you have to pass 2 or 3 parameters.

```
window.postMessage(data, origin, [transfer])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to add *webworker* to your tsconfig.json or create a separate TS project for your worker, because postMessage has a different API in the [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) and in the [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) environment.

```
"compilerOptions" : {
    "lib": [
        "webworker"
```

Comment: adding "webworker" clashed with "dom", to create a project with both i had to follow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356655/structuring-a-typescript-project-with-workers